# Use differentials to estimate the error in volume of the box.

Tags: calculus, volume

In a manufacturing process the boxes with nominal dimensions of $5$ inches by $5$ inches by $2$ inches are subject to an error of $1\%$ in each dimension.Use differentials to estimate the error in volume of the box. Compare it with the actual minimum and maximum value of the box.

I do not know how we can solve such a problem. I am completely lost. Please help me.

Comment: the volume is $5\times 5\times \times 2=50$

Comment: Can I use this? if we take $x=5,y=5,z=2$ then $V=xyz$ this implies $dv=yzdx+xzdy+xydz=0.1+0.1+0.25=0.45$

Comment: so error in volume is $45\%$,Is this correct?

Comment: And what should I do about the the second part?Its comparison with maximum and minimum value of the box?I do not know the maximum and minimum value of the box.

Comment: $dv$ has units of volume. $dv/v = 0.9 \%$.

Comment: I guess the maximum volume is the volume obtained when all lenghts are the longest -- add 1 % to all lengths. Similar for the minimum volume.

Comment: You will obtain that the estimated error $dv$ will differ from the difference $v - v_\text{max}$ or $v - v_\text{min}$. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume of a box with dimensions $a$, $b$, $c$ is given by
$$V(a,b,c)=a\>b\>c\ .$$
It follows that
$${dV(a,b,c)\over V(a,b,c)}={da\over a}+{db\over b}+{dc\over c}\ .$$
Therefore, "in first approximation", the relative error in volume is the sum of the relative errors in the side lengths.

In the given example the relative errors in the side lengths are $1\%$. As the case may be these add up, and we obtain a relative volume error of $3\%$, or $1.5$ cubic inches as a "first estimate".

The actual minimal volume of the box under the given constraints is $$4.95\cdot 4.95\cdot1.98=48.51495$$
cubic inches, which is $<1.5$ cubic inches off; and the maximal volume is
$$5.05\cdot5.05\cdot2.02=51.51505$$
cubic inches, which is $1.51505>1.5$ off the intended value of $50$ cubic inches. It follows that the worst case analysis gives a larger error than the "first estimate".